# Can I print '1' n times without using a loop in C programming?

Tags: c, time, syntax

When we use python, we can print same string multiple times by using `print("1"*n)`. This helps to reduce the execution time. If we have a method to do that in C, it would be helpful.

Expected result is the time complexity of O(n).

Comment: If you wish to reduce execution time, I would look into making sure that output device is buffered, rather than trying to avoid loops.

Comment: You could use recursion, but that won't reduce execution time but recursion it's still some kind of loop. Anyway, I/O is pretty slow per definition, so the whole question is pretty pointless. BTW the time complexity of a loop is O(n)....

Comment: `print("1"*n)` in python will also use some kind of a loop internally. You just don't have to write it explicitly like you have to in C.

Comment: Perl has the `x` operator for the same job.  Both Python and Perl allow the LHS to be a multi-character string that will be repeated in its entirety.  The LHS is not limited to a single character.  Several of the solutions shown do not easily translate to handle multi-character strings on the LHS.

Comment: Looping means doing the same thing repeatedly. What makes you think `"1"*n` doesn't loop?

Comment: In fact `print()` function is not relevant to the point of this question - execution time/complexity. The only relevant is creation time of string.

In python the expression `str*n` create string with length n*len(str) and copy it's content n-times there. How you can achieve this without loop?

In python implementation there is also loop used and it's time complexity is O(n): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce00de4c8cd39816f992e749c1074487d93abe9d/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12159

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language.

When you write something like:

```
print("1"*n)
```

The Python interpreter performs a loop internally.

It is more efficient in Python because the interpreter is usually written in a compiled language like C (or C++) and so the loop is more efficient when done internally.

But since C itself is a compiled language writting a simple loop (which will be done in **O(n)** as you requested), is the most efficient thing you can do. This loop can be either "manually" written or via some library function like `memset` which is implemented with a loop.
Note that such a loop can be replaced with a recursion, but this is not expected to improve performance (recursion is *usually less efficient* than a simple loop).

The most "expensive" operation in this case is actually the I/O which might be buffered.
So the best you can do might be to build the final string (with a loop) into a buffer, and then use one `printf` statement to dump it the console.

As usual with matters of performance, you should profile it to check.

**Note:**
The answer above assumes that `n` isn't known in advance, and can be arbitrarily large.
I used this assumption because:
(1) The python statement used as a reference hints to that.
(2) The OP mentioned O(n) complexity which is meaningful only when `n` is relatively large.

Comment: It is using loops internally :). Basically you cant

Comment: @gulpr isn't that what I wrote (both regarding the Python interpreter and C library functions like `memset`) ?

Comment: Recursion vs. iteration is a programming concept. It is not valid to assume anything about how the code is actually translated and/or executed.

Comment: I agree. But from my experience recursion is rarely (if at all) implemented more efficiently than a simple loop. And the OP seems to be concerned with performance. In the python case, as I explained, a hand-written loop (or recursion for that matter) is expected to be much slower than `"1"*n`, but this is not the case in C.

Answer (score 1):

It seems in this expression "1"*n there is built a string with n characters that is outputted. In C you have to build such a string yourself by using for example a variable length array. Something like the following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_n( int n )
{
    if ( n > 0 )
    {
        char s[n];
        memset(s, '1', n );
        printf( "%.*s\n", n, s );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think this answer actually misses the issue in this post. The OP has a misunderstanding that I tried to address in my answer. Your answer is indeed without a visible loop, but it is simply hidden in the `memset`. In my answer I tried to explain this issue.

Comment: @wohlstad In some systems memset can be done with one mashine instruction.

Comment: I understand it can be done for specific and small `n` (up to a few bytes), but how can this be done for an unknown (and arbitrarily large) `n` ?

Comment: @wohlstad n is known within the function.

Comment: The OP referred to `print("1"*n)` in Python as a base for their question. In that reference `n` can be anything. It can be an arbitrarily large number received e.g. from a user input. In that general case I don't see how `memset` can be implemented as a single machine instruction. The mention of O(n) by the OP also hints that `n` is not limited to relatively small values (because in that case big-O analysis is not relevant at all).

Comment: @wohlstad The value of n is loaded in some register as for example ECX and a corresponding instruction is executed. In any case memset is much quicker then a manually written loop because it is optimized.

Comment: I agree with your last point. But I doubt it will give a benefit similar to the one in Python (because in Python there a huge difference between a hand written loop, and a loop executed internally by the interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use recursion to print "1" n times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printOne(int n) {
// Base case: if n is 0, stop recursion
if (n == 0)
    return;

// Print 1
printf("1 ");

// Recursively call printOne with n-1
printOne(n - 1);
}

int main() {
int n;

// Get input from the user
printf("Enter the number of times to print 1: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

// Call the recursive function
printOne(n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I doubt this will reduce execution time. Most likely it will increase it.

Comment: Correct but it will still be O(n), which the OP asked for.

Comment: Yes but so will a simple loop. And the OP also mentioned _"to reduce the execution time"_.

Comment: He mentioned in his title that he is looking for a solution without using a loop. You are correct in saying that it will not reduce execution time. But I think what OP means by that is a "cleaner" way which requires lesser code.

Comment: And why do you think using recursion is cleaner in any way that a simple loop ?

Comment: My answer doesn't satisfy his "cleaner" code part but it satisfies his requirement of printing 1 n times without loop.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think you missed the fact that the OP has a misunderstanding about the issue. I tried to clarify it in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want loops use recursion.

```
void printntimes(const char ch, size_t times)
{
    if(!times) return;
    printntimes(ch, times - 1);
    fputc(ch, stdout);
}


int main(void)
{
    printntimes('1', 5);
}
```

Comment: See my comments under Aman Aggarwal's answer. Basically I think the OP has some misunderstadning that I tried to clarify in my answer. I don't see how a recursion is better in any way than a loop in this case. The OP requested a non-loop solution assuming it is more efficient, but I believe a recursion will not help in this respect.